# Procedure in converting int to decimal data type?

Tags: php, mysql, decimal, int, types

I have an `int(11)` column which is used to store money. I read some of the answers on SO and it seems I just need to update it to be a `decimal (19,4)` data type.

Are there any gotchas I should know about before I actually do the converting? My application is in PHP/Zend and I'm not using an ORM so I doubt I would need to update any sort of class to consistently identify the data type.

Comment: 4 decimal digits? what currency you gonna store?

Comment: There shouldn't be any issue with altering the data type in the table, but operations on the data are suspect -- which we have no idea about from your post...

Comment: @Col - USD. It's just that `19,4` was in one of the answers. I guess `19,2` will do for USD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (
    -> id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> money INT(11) NOT NULL,
    -> PRIMARY KEY(id))
    -> ENGINE = MyISAM;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> DESCRIBE t1;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment
| money | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM t1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1 (money) VALUES (`10.01`);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '10.01' in 'field list'
mysql> INSERT INTO t1 (money) VALUES ('10.01');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM t1;
+----+-------+
| id | money |
+----+-------+
|  1 |    10 |
+----+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY COLUMN money DECIMAL(19,4);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM t1;
+----+---------+
| id | money   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | 10.0000 |
+----+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1 (money) VALUES ('10.12');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM t1;
+----+---------+
| id | money   |
+----+---------+
|  1 | 10.0000 |
|  2 | 10.1200 |
+----+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

You don't have any problem with dd when you alter int to decimal. But you should review your PHP code to ensure that your code works with decimal value correctly.

Comment: Hehe, that's style: keeping your mistyped backticks instead of quotes in the output :)